# How to save html form in django as i given below

Tags: django

**HTML**

```
<form action="/tcgsave/" method="POST" onsubmit="return" >{% csrf_token %}

     <p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" maxlength="60" name="name"type="text">{{testcaseName}} </input></p>
  <input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

**views.py To save the form data**

def tcgsave(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    testcase_name = request.POST.get('id_name')
    print testcase_name

    testcaseName = request.POST['id_name']
    print testcaseName
    testcase_name.save()
```

**when i click on save button it give me null value for testcase_name**

Comment: Check out the contents of request.POST rather than getting specific values.  Also look at pdb/ipdb rather than printing out variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should use name attribute of input instead of id:

```
request.POST.get('name')
```

in your case